# SQL Query to get a total value for each week across years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL query in SQL Server, and I hope I can explain what I am after. I have several years of data. Here is a sample of some of the database.

[image]

What I am wanting to do is get the total number of Bovine for values New_Zealand per week.

So for week 2013-01-12 the total value would be 36080 (Sum of New Zealand where Animal is Bovine for that week). Repeat this for all weeks in the database.

I currently have this SQL select statement.

```
SELECT SUM(New_Zealand) 
FROM Slaughter_Data 
WHERE Animal = 'Bovine' 
  AND WeekEndingDate BETWEEN '2010-01-04' AND '2015-01-03' 
  AND New_Zealand IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, WeekEndingDate)
```

This is wrong because it gives me 52 weeks, with all New_Zealand values summed where Animal = Bovine, and summed for that week across all years. I want it for each year. Can anyone tell me what I need to change?

I hope I have made myself clear and let me know if I haven't so I can clarify.

Comment: You would need to add year to your group by. If at all possible I would consider normalizing your structure so you don't have countries as columns in your data. It looks like a number of other pieces could stand some normalization too.

Comment: You would also need to group by year

Comment: New_Zealand is actually a derived column in a view. The actual database does not contain that column just North_Island and South_Island. Are you suggesting that I have one column for values and then another that differentiates them as either north or south island? Sean any suggestions you have for normalising the data would be welcome as I am new to all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about grouping by `WeekEndingDate`, since it will get your the number for that week in that year.

```
SELECT SUM(New_Zealand)
FROM Slaughter_Data
WHERE Animal = 'Bovine'
    AND WeekEndingDate BETWEEN '2010-01-04' AND '2015-01-03'
    AND New_Zealand IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY WeekEndingDate
```

Comment: What happens if I do that is it combines all values for each week across years. i.e. all values week 1 in 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 will be combined. I have actually manged to solve it will post the answer as I think this will be beneficial to other people. If someone has a better answer I will mark that as correct. I'm quite new to SQL so learning as I go. Would love peoples comments on whether my data needs normalizing though.

Comment: I think you are referring to `Week_number` where as I am referring to `WeekEndingDate`, which should be unique for a week in a year.

Comment: No I tried that. It combined all values across years into that same week?

Comment: Based on your data, that's not possible! An aggregation on  WeekEndingDate like '2013-01-03' cannot combine values across other years.

Comment: It seems you are correct. I could have sworn though that I tried that first because that seemed the obvious thing to do. For some reason i was getting it grouped all in one week. So thank you. Have adjusted it accordingly.