# Selecting sets of data and creating a new column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server can you select the first set of values (i.e. week numbers 1 - 52) give them another value in a new column, then select the next lot of values.

The problem I am having is the data table I am working on has week numbers for each financial year, which starts the first Sunday after 1 October. So it simply iterates 1 - 52 for each financial year.

I am trying to make a column in a view that grabs the first 52 gives them the a financial year value of 1, then grabs the next 52 and gives them a financial year value of 2 etc (obviously with year 1 starting at the first record). I do have the Week Ending Date column to work with also.

Here is a snippet of the table:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: doesn't your WeekEndingDate precisely tell you which fiscal year it is, since every date belongs to one and only one fiscal year?

Comment: Refer to this question ask by you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180653/sql-query-to-get-a-total-value-for-each-week-across-years

Comment: Yes but this changes depending on the year. i.e. first sunday from October. Are you saying this would be the way to organise it?

Comment: you can calculate the first Sunday of October using datediff() and datepart() SQL functions; what is minimum and maximum WeekEndingDate in whole table? what is the name of the column that should contain fiscal year?

Comment: The week numbers will always be 1 - 52, the column containing the fiscal year can be anything just fiscal_year would be fine as I havn't made it yet.

Comment: Souttrain I'm not sure that answers my question. For example, The current Week Ending Date is 2015-01-03 and Week_number 14. The week ending date for the previous year, where week number = 14 is 2014-01-04. So I can't simply say where the week is less than the current date minus a year. Perhaps I could use the Sunday of that and it would work. But I still would like to know the answer to the above question and whether you can iterate through sets of data as I mentioned.

Comment: Is the table continuous? I mean: for every year there is at least one record for each of week 1-52?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the Sundays and Octobers. If I understand correctly, you only need to assign a rank to each occurrence of week number in order of the ending dates.

Please try this (but use copy of the table or transaction to check first; of course `T` is name of your table):

```
update T
    set fiscal_year = YearNumbers.FiscalYear
from T
    inner join
    (
        select WeekEndingDate, WeekNumber, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by WeekNumber order by WeekEndingDate) as FiscalYear
        from T
    ) as YearNumbers
    on T.WeekEndingDate = YearNumbers.WeekEndingDate and T.WeekNumber = YearNumbers.WeekNumber
```

Comment: That isn't quite working. It is including values from multiple years. It might be something I am doing wrong. But for Fiscal year 1 the first six values when ordered by FiscalYear, Week_Ending_Date I get 1/1/2011, 1/11/2014, 1/18/2014, 1/25/2014, 1/3/2015, 10/1/2011?

Comment: So either I do not understand what you want to achieve, or there is something in your data that I am not aware of. I do not quite understand your comment. Can you paste the final query text, that you execute, and what values you get vs. what values you expect to get?

Comment: This format: m/d/y and order you shown here suggest that your date was sorted as string. Why is that so? Do you show results from some application?